# Kibana Index Pattern showing wrong results

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, logstash-jdbc

I am using ELK stack in which i have used jdbc input in logstash
I have created 2 indexes

> 1. users
> 2. employees

Both the indexes have one same column `objid`
**Logstash config file**

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/application/cmt/ELK/logstash-5.3.0/ojdbc14.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx:abc"
    jdbc_user => "xxxx"
    jdbc_password => "xxxxx"
    schedule => "*/2 * * * *"
    statement => "select * from table_employee"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "employees"
    document_type => "employee"
    document_id => "%{objid}"
    hosts => "xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9200"
    }
}

input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/application/cmt/ELK/logstash-5.3.0/ojdbc14.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx:abc"
    jdbc_user => "xx"
    jdbc_password => "xxxxxxx"
    schedule => "*/2 * * * *"
    statement => "select A.OBJID,A.LOGIN_NAME,A.STATUS,A.USER_ACCESS2PRIVCLASS,A.USER_DEFAULT2WIPBIN,A.SUPVR_DEFAULT2MONITOR,A.USER2RC_CONFIG,A.OFFLINE2PRIVCLASS,A.WIRELESS_EMAIL from table_user a where A.STATUS=1"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "users"
    document_type => "user"
    document_id => "%{objid}%{login_name}"
    hosts => "xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9200"
    }
}
```

1st input jdbc 'employees' contains `26935` records

2nd input jdbc 'users' contains `10619` records

Common Records : `9635` ( objid matches )

***1st problem*** is that when i create an index pattern in kibana as '

> users

It's showing count of `37554` ,why ? it should show only `10619`

***2nd problem*** : when i create an index pattern as '

> employees

It's showing count of `27919` ,why ? it should show only `26935`

Also i have create different document Id for index 'users'  `%{objid}%{login_name}`

Answer (score 1):

If your users and employees input and output are in the same file/executed at the same time, as what your example shows, you need to use conditionals to route your data to the correct elasticsearch index. Logstash concatenates your files/file into one pipeline, so all your inputs run through all of the filters/outputs, which is likely why you're getting unexpected results. See this [discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/solved-multiple-logstash-config-file/51692/2).

You will need to do something like this:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    statement => "SELECT * FROM users"
    type => "users"
  }
}

input {
  jdbc {
    statement => "SELECT * FROM employees"
    type => "employees"
  }
}

output {
  if [type] == "users" {
    elasticsearch {
      index => "users"
      document_type => "user"
      document_id => "%{objid}%{login_name}"
      hosts => "xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9200"
    }
  }

  if [type] == "employees" {
    elasticsearch {
      index => "employees"
      document_type => "employee"
      document_id => "%{objid}"
      hosts => "xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9200"
    }
  }  
}
```